# Bootstrap 4 - showing a list of items with texts and icons correctly

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4, fontello

Using Bootstrap 4 I can create a list of list-items. Each list-item contains a text and a button with an icon. The icon is taken from [Fontello](http://fontello.com/).

On mobile screens (XS media) sometimes the button does not take the icon as button-content. The result is a very small button that does not contain the icon. This looks like on a mobile device:

[image]

On Chrome on my Desktop (F12, XS device) the result is as expected.

**A diagnosis is**: When I add a number of rows, then vertical size of the list-item gets smaller. Adding 10 items, and the list-item is just a few mm high! So, the size of the list-item gets less high, the button gets less high. Has this to do with '**flexbox**'?

**Why is this so?** I know that when you omit to put anything (or any text) in the button, the button will remain very small. **How to repair this?**

The code for the button (inside Angular 6)

```
<ul class="list-group" id="cachesOnHikeList">
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex flex-row" *ngFor="let cacheonhike of cachesonhike">
        <div class="flex-grow-1">{{ cacheonhike.name| slice:0:22 }}</div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" (click)="removeGeocache( cacheonhike.gcid)"><i class="icon-cancel-circled"></i></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The 'cachesOnHikeList' CSS class is:

```
#cachesOnHikeList {
  /*max-height: 250px;*/
  max-height:35vh;
  overflow:auto;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**Plan-B** does not work either. This code (with 2 characters added as button text) produces the same results:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm px-1" 
(click)="removeGeocache( cacheonhike.gcid)">&nbsp;<i class="icon-cancel-circled"></i>&nbsp;</button>
```

**Plan-C**: Adding a 'real' character as button text does not help. The 'X' is shown below the small button. The button is similar to the ones on the screenshot.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm px-1 font-weight-bold" 
(click)="removeGeocache( cacheonhike.gcid)">X</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of the small buttons may be caused by (my/the) use of flexbox in combination with a scrollable list-groups

**Solution 1**:

Replace the flexbox solution with the BS4 grid.

```
<ul class="list-group" id="cachesOnHikeList">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let cacheonhike of cachesonhike">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="mr-auto">{{ cacheonhike.naam | slice:0:22 }}</div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm font-weight-bold col-2 col-sm-1 px-1" (click)="removeGeocache( cacheonhike.gcid)">X</button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Solution 2**: responsive BS4 table

Using a Bootstrap 4 table that is Responsive. In this case the width of the columns is determine automatically by Bootstrap.

```
<div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="listMaxEntries">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>GcId</th>
                    <th>Naam</th>
                    <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">Type</th>
                    <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell">Actief</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let geocache of geocachesPage.geocaches"
                    (click)="saveGeocacheInApplicationDataAndEditIt( geocache)">
                    <td>{{ geocache.gcid | slice:0:9 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ geocache.naam }}</td>
                    <td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">{{ geocache.type }}</td>
                    <td class="d-none d-md-table-cell">{{ geocache.actief }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 3**: BS4 table with Flexbox.

Using this solution you can specify the column widths. In this case the row height is good!

```
<div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="listMaxEntries">
        <table id="productSizes" class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <th class="col-3 col-md-2">GcId</th>
                <th class="col-9 col-sm-7 col-md-5">Name</th>
                <th class="col-sm-3 d-none d-sm-table-cell">Type</th>
                <th class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-table-cell">Actief</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let geocache of geocachesPage.geocaches" class="d-flex"
                (click)="saveGeocacheInApplicationDataAndEditIt( geocache)">
                <td class="col-3 col-md-2">{{ geocache.gcid | slice:0:9 }}</td>
                <td class="col-9 col-sm-7 col-md-5">{{ geocache.naam }}</td>
                <td class="col-sm-3 d-none d-sm-table-cell">{{ geocache.type }}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-table-cell">{{ geocache.actief }}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Enjoy Bootstrap 4** -- what a very nice package!